# Create a new sheet everytime the first cell of a row has a specific value - Excel

Tags: excel

I need to split a sheet in multiple sheets based on a cell value like in the example below.
Basically, every time there is the value xyz in the first cell of a row I need a new sheet with all the rows between this xyz and the next.

I tried many plugins but unsuccessfully. My visual basic/macro knowledge are far limited...I usually edit the code obtained from the "record macro".

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | row |
| dolor | row |
| ipsum | row |
| xyz | row |
| ipsum | row |
| dolor | row |
| dolor | row |
| xyz | row |
| dolor | row |

and I want

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | row |
| dolor | row |
| ipsum | row |

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | row |
| ipsum | row |
| dolor | row |
| dolor | row |

| A header | Another header |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | row |
| dolor | row |

Comment: It would be useful to know why the downvote. Otherwise it has no meaning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA is definitely the best way to do this in Excel. First, you have to loop through your table, I would use a While loop and check if the cell is blank/empty. Then, you just copy the cell contents from the first/complete sheet to the last sheet. The hard part is creating a new sheet every time the loop sees the special string. This part I figured out using the Record Macros option.

```
while (first sheet's current cell is not blank)
    if cell content is special string
        add new sheet to end
    endif
    copy cell content from first sheet to last sheet
end
```

I made some sample VBA code based on your example table, but it does assume the string that triggers a new sheet is always the same and the headers are always the same. If you notice that a table did not split where you expected it to, you might want to check for capitals vs lower case or unexpected blank spaces. This also doesn't delete any existing sheets so if you run it multiple times, you will end up with lots of new sheets.

```
Sub SplitIntoSheets()
' Split full table into multiple tables with
' string "xyz" as first cell

' All tables have the same headers
header1 = "A header"
header2 = "Another header"
' This is what string will trigger a new sheet/table
newList = "xyz"

' Begin at cell 2 to skip header
' i is total counter, j is individual sheet's counter
i = 2
j = 2

' Continue until you reach an empty cell
While (Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) <> "")
    ' Check for special string, if found, create new sheet
    If Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = newList Then
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Cells(1, 1).Value = header1
        Cells(1, 2).Value = header2
        j = 2
    End If
    ' Copy cell values from full list to current sheet
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(j, 1).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value
    Sheets(Sheets.Count).Cells(j, 2).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value
    j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Like a moron I forgot to post my code but for me (with minors changes) yours works.